# What is the difference between Button and Androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton in Android Development?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to create a Sign Up page in the latest Android Studio Arctic. So I am trying to customize and style the buttons using Button Class, but no observable changes were made, until I used AppCompatButton, and all the styles and customization for the button were implemented. I want an elaboration between the two Views and why I could not make the changes using Button Class. Thanks.

These are the codes for AppCompatButton and Button

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/sign_up_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_border_signin"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:text="Sign Up"
                android:textColor="#e0e0e0e0"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Button

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_up_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_border_signin"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:text="Sign Up"
                android:textColor="#e0e0e0e0"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Understanding the difference is as simple as going to: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatButton

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Possible Reason**

You might be using some features that are not compatible for older versions in your background drawable file.

---

**Difference between Button and AppCompatButton**

An AppCompatButton is simply a [Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) which supports compatible features on older versions of the platform, including:

- Allows dynamic tint of its background via the background tint methods in [ViewCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/ViewCompat).
- Allows setting of the background tint using [R.attr.backgroundTint](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/R.attr#backgroundTint) and [R.attr.backgroundTintMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/R.attr#backgroundTintMode).
- Allows setting of the font family using [R.attr.fontFamily](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#fontFamily)

This will automatically be used when you use Button in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

**Source:** [AppCompatButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatButton)

Comment: "You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views". Can you elaborate on this statement?

Comment: This way custom views with AppCompatButton will be backward compatible i.e will support older versions of the platform.